# Migrating from Zimbra to Google G-Suite for Email Hosting

Tags: email, migration, google-workspace, zimbra

So, we have a server running Ubuntu 10.10 that hosts our Zimbra email server.   I would like to move away from using Zimbra and I think the best option for the company I work for would be a hosted email solution like GSuite but I do not have any experience migrating from one email server to another and I have a few questions.

Our email domain is @poweron.com, and I would prefer if we could keep this email domain for hosting our email, but obviously this will mean that the old server cannot still exist at that domain name.

Are there any good, open source tools to help me with migrating all of our existing email from approx 75 email inboxes to Google G Suite?  Some people at this company have email addresses that they have been using for over a decade at this point, so migrating email between the two systems seems like it will be a huge PITA - but I was wondering if I could get some suggestions for how to approach a project of this scale from other IT professionals who have real world experience moving from one email server to another.

Another possibility I was thinking of was purchasing a different domain name to use for hosting the G Suite accounts, and then have any email that is sent to the old domain name be forwarded to the new mail domain.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you will only do once, and you will want to get it right that one time.

I suggest you at least consider outsourcing this task.  That way you can focus on your day-to-day work, you don't need to learn the ins and outs of a tool you will hopefully never use again, and the people you support will likely have a better experience.

With regard to the transfer of the domain, I recommend you move the domain name over to G-Suite unless you really like running the Zimbra server (my experience was that it was fine as mail servers go, but I prefer not having to run a mail server by a lot)

That might look like configuring one mail system to forward all mail to the other (Not hard in Zimbra as I recall, and Google offers the ability to do even clever things like routing email for accounts that aren't in G-Suite yet).

You might choose to set up subdomain MXes to simplify your life, like zimbra.company.com having an MX setting for your Zimbra server(s), and google.company.com having an MX setting for GMail.  That way you can forward email to bob@google.company.com or bob@zimbra.google.com for the duration of your transition.

If you enjoy the details of running a mail server, then this is your chance to shine.  If it is just part of your job, and you have other parts that are interesting too, then I'd at least balance the cost for outsourcing against the cost of your time and personal life for the transition (and the cost to the company of any missteps).  Since you are migrating away from a mail server you are in charge of to a cloud service, I suspect you recognize the value of services offered by others.